# Angular2 queryselector across components

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, selectors-api

I currently am trying to test if my login page shows a correct error message when someone tries to loging with wrong credentials. The problem is that my error-message functionallity goes across 2 components ( unlike the other tests I've written, which work perfectly) and I'm unsure how to test this. Do I test the fixture of my main component or the fixture of my alert-component? below is some of the code I've written

```
 it('should show an error message when login is not a success', async(() =>{

component.model.username = "muXAXO";
component.model.password = "12345";


alertFixture.detectChanges();
fixture.detectChanges();
elLoginButton.click();
alertFixture.detectChanges();
fixture.detectChanges();

fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
  alertFixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  elErrorWrongCredentials = alertFixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.alerrt');
  expect(elErrorWrongCredentials.textContent).toContain('Authentication Failed: Bad credentials');
});



}));
```

Fixture is created with the current component I'm testing
AlertFixture is created with the component that gets called in my HTML.

So in my HTML I have this (this shows me the alert message I'm trying to test):

```
     <div id="container" class="bottom">
        <alert class="alerrt"></alert>
    </div>
```

and then I also have an alert-component that gets used to show that alert message in the above HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="message" class="alerrt" [ngClass]="{ 'alert': message, 'alert-success': message.type === 'success', 'alert-danger': message.type === 'error' }">{{message.text}}</div>
```

Any ideas? The current code gives me this error:

> TypeError: cannot read property 'textcontent' of null

So for some reason he is unable to find the 'alerrt' class (I guess because he only searches in the component that belongs to the test class)